# Analogues to unzip in R

Tags: r

Trying to learn some R after doing mostly Haskell for rather a long time I got stuck on a problem I would usually have using `unzip`<sup>1</sup> and `map`.

I have a sequence of strings, each containing two substrings separated by an underscore. I want to "unzip" this sequence into something like a data frame or a matrix, where the first column is the sequence of all the first substrings and the second column the sequence of all the second substrings.

Is there any analogue to `unzip` in R, and would it be considered ideomatic to use it here, or am I approaching this from alltogether the wrong direction?

[1] Given a list (or more generally any kind of sequence) of pairs `unzip` produces a pair of lists, in the obvious way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track.  You want `strsplit`

```
vec <- paste(letters,letters[26:1],sep='_')
out <- strsplit(vec,'_')
```

thats a list.. and sapply will get the vectors out.

```
data.frame(one = sapply(out,'[',1), two = sapply(out,'[',2))
```

Comment: I always forget that operations are vectorised, works great, thanks! Also, does '[' give you the access operator, or how does that work?

Comment: `?'['`.  It is the "subset" function of sorts.  the third argument (1 or 2 in this example) to it is which element of the subset I want out.  so `sapply` applies the function `[` to each list element of `out`. its like writing `c(out[[1]][1], out[[2]][1], etc.)`

Comment: I didn't realise you could do it like that, very nice! Thanks

Comment: There is also strapply: `library(gsubfn);  strapply(vec, "[^_]", c, simplify = rbind)` .

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Great function! I learn something new every day!  Is there anything it cant do...